# Is there a command to diff all the kept files in accurev?

Tags: diff, accurev

I am new to accurev, used to use SVN earlier. I want to a get diff file consisting of all the changes in kept files in a given directory. I know `ac diff -b <file>`
 gives diff in a file, but if I have many files and I want the diff of all the kept files in a given directory, is there a straight forward command to do this like svn diff?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are going to need to create a script if you only want to diff kept files in a given directory.  Basically you will run an 'accurev stat -k' -> parse output for given directory -> 'accurev diff -b'

Comment: something like this, ac stat -k TestCases/*|sed -n 's/[\S]*\s.*//p'|xargs ac diff -b..But I ended up using a gui client which made it all much simpler.

Answer (score 0):

On a *NIX machine the commands below work nicely.

The -k option to AccuRev's stat command says find the file with "(kept)" status. Using the -fal options to stat provides just the Depot relative pathway to the file. No addition filtering needed. So the command line would be:

**accurev stat -k -fal  | xargs accurev diff -b**

Produces output like:

```
accurev stat -k -fal  | xargs accurev diff -b 
diffing element /./COPYING
341a342
> Tue Mar 18 08:38:39 EDT 2014
> Change for demo purposes.
diffing element /./INSTALL
3a4,7
> New Change
> 
> Another Change
>
```

Dave